# Connecting to MongoDB from AWS Glue

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, connection, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to create a connection from AWS Glue to MongoDB, but when I test the connection it fails with error: "Check that your connection definition references your Mongo database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Exiting with error code 30". I know that my connection parameters are correct because I can connect with the same host, port, database, user name, and password from another client application (DataGrip). And I know that my VPC configuration should be correct too because I have another connection in the Glue, to connect to the PostgreSQL database on-premise with public IP, that works just fine.
My MongoDB version is 4.4.1. I am out of ideas what else can cause the problem. Is anyone successfully connects to MongoDB form Glue and run the Crawler?

Comment: Hey Igor. Could you solve this problem? I'm having same here. Not very friendly right?

Comment: I was trying to solve this issue with Amazon Support for the last month. Finally, we pinpointed it to the problem with Java truststore and SSL MongoDB connection. They are using a custom truststore, that is missing IdenTrust DST Root CA X3 certificate. They do not have ETA on the fix, but suggested it will happen not earlier than end of January.

Comment: Hey Igor. did you ever get this solved? Getting exact same issue using peered connection from atas.

Comment: Any solution or workaround to get this sorted? I am having the same issue with a vpc peering connection to mongo atlas

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Does anyone have any solution around this?

Comment: That is an issue on the AWS side for MongoDB as well as MySQL. Please check with AWS Support for resolution.

Comment: @IgorProshkin You can answer your own question. Your information is useful.

Comment: @Nikk I think its only with MySQL 8, isn't it? Because for sure I used MySQL with glue without issues.

Comment: @Rajat0612 There is no solution for now. Its internal AWS problem. You have to not use Glue or migrate your db if possible.

Comment: Having the same issue and not even using the BI Connector + JDBC-connection from Glue works so def. an issue on the AWS side.